# i try to write the iso to a usb flashdrive

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, iso

it fales when i try to write the iso to usb

this is the log file of rufus

```
Rufus version: 2.18.1213
Windows version: Windows 10 64-bit (Build 16299)
Syslinux versions: 4.07/2013-07-25, 6.03/2014-10-06
Grub versions: 0.4.6a, 2.02
System locale ID: 0x0413
Will use default UI locale 0x0413
SetLGP: Successfully set NoDriveTypeAutorun policy to 0x0000009E
Localization set to 'nl-NL'
Found USB device 'Generic Flash Disk USB Device' (058F:6387) [ID]
1 device found
No volume information for drive 0x82
Disk type: Removable, Disk size: 16GB, Sector size: 512 bytes
Cylinders: 2048, Tracks per cylinder: 255, Sectors per track: 63
Partition type: MBR, NB Partitions: 1
Disk ID: 0x000915DD
Drive has a Syslinux Master Boot Record
Partition 1:
  Type: FAT32 LBA (0x0c)
  Size: 15.7 GB (16847470592 bytes)
  Start Sector: 2048, Boot: Yes
Scanning image...
ISO analysis:
  Image is an ISO9660 image
  Will use '/isolinux/isolinux.cfg' for Syslinux
  Detected Syslinux version: 6.03/20151222 (from '/isolinux/isolinux.bin')
Disk image analysis:
  Image has an unknown Master Boot Record
  Image is a bootable disk image
ISO label: 'Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS amd64'
  Size: 1.5 GB (Projected)
  Has a >64 chars filename
  Uses: Syslinux/Isolinux v6.03
  Uses: EFI
  Note: This ISO uses symbolic links, which will not be replicated due to file system limitations.
  Because of this, some features from this image may not work...
Using image: ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso (1.5 GB)
Will reuse 'ldlinux.sys' and 'ldlinux.bss' from './rufus_files/rufus_files/syslinux-6.03/20151222/' for Syslinux installation

Format operation started
Requesting disk access...
Opened \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2 for exclusive write access
Requesting lock...
Will use 'E:' as volume mountpoint
Requesting lock...
Analyzing existing boot records...
Drive has a Syslinux Master Boot Record
Volume has an unknown Partition Boot Record
Clearing MBR/PBR/GPT structures...
Erasing 128 sectors
Deleting partitions...
Partitioning (MBR)...
Closing existing volume...
Waiting for logical drive to reappear...
Formatting (FAT32)...
Using cluster size: 8192 bytes
Quick format was selected
Creating file system...
Format completed.
Writing master boot record...
Drive has a Zeroed Master Boot Record
Partition is already FAT32 LBA...
Set bootable USB partition as 0x80
Using Syslinux MBR
Found volume GUID \\?\Volume{a780b8b8-f967-11e7-9d1f-806e6f6e6963}\
Installing Syslinux 6.03...
Opened \\?\Volume{a780b8b8-f967-11e7-9d1f-806e6f6e6963} for shared write access
Using existing './rufus_files/syslinux-6.03/20151222/ldlinux.sys' ✓
Using existing './rufus_files/syslinux-6.03/20151222/ldlinux.bss' ✗
Successfully wrote 'ldlinux.sys'
Successfully wrote Syslinux boot record
Successfully remounted \\?\Volume{a780b8b8-f967-11e7-9d1f-806e6f6e6963}\ on E:
Copying ISO files...
Extracting files...
Image is an ISO9660 image
This image will be extracted using Rock Ridge extensions (if present)
Extracting: E:\.disk\base_installable (0 bytes)
  Unable to create file: [0x00000057] De parameter is onjuist.
Unable to create E:\syslinux.cfg - booting from USB will not work

Found USB device 'Generic Flash Disk USB Device' (058F:6387) [ID]
1 device found
No volume information for drive 0x82
Disk type: Removable, Disk size: 16GB, Sector size: 512 bytes
Cylinders: 2048, Tracks per cylinder: 255, Sectors per track: 63
Partition type: MBR, NB Partitions: 1
Disk ID: 0x000E3BAD
Drive has a Syslinux Master Boot Record
Partition 1:
  Type: FAT32 LBA (0x0c)
  Size: 15.7 GB (16847470592 bytes)
  Start Sector: 2048, Boot: Yes
Closed Windows format prompt
```

Comment: You might get a useful answer from Rufus or Windows support. Ubuntu is merely the payload.

Answer (score 1):

Rufus developer here.

Pretty sure this is indicative of a defective USB drive. Have you tried with a different flash drive?

Also, but this shouldn't be directly relevant to your error, I am very puzzled on how you got an `✗` instead of a `✓` on `ldlinux.bss`. This indicates that the SHA-256 of the file you downloaded doesn't match the one from our server (which Rufus 2.18 will validate), meaning that either you modified that file manually, or your download got corrupted or (but this is unlikely), something even more sinister like someone deliberately intercepting the download and replacing it with their own content.

All in all, I see lots of signs that seem to point to unstable hardware or system, which probably explains your issue.

One last thing you may want to try is, when you create the bootable drive in Rufus, you **will** be prompted on whether you want to write the image in ISO image mode or DD mode, with a notice that specifically tells that, if you find that you have issues in ISO mode, you may want to try creating the USB drive in DD mode. Have you tried writing the drive in DD mode?